# count and print unique values from python dict

Tags: python-2.7

my python dict looks like

```
{'1, ': ('      name', '10G')}
{'2, ': ('      name', '10G')}
{'3, ': ('      name2', '40G')}
{'4, ': ('      name2', '40G')}
```

Keys are 1 to 4
and values are 
name* , *G

result I want to get using python :
no of 10G entries = 2 and 
no of 40G entries = 2

What will be the python code?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Counter`

```
>>> a = {
         '1, ': ('      name', '10G'),
         '2, ': ('      name', '10G'),
         '3, ': ('      name2', '40G'),
         '4, ': ('      name2', '40G')
        }
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(a.values())
>>> c
Counter({('      name2', '40G'): 2, ('      name', '10G'): 2})
>>> list(c.iteritems())
[(('      name2', '40G'), 2), (('      name', '10G'), 2)]
```